# Can I close question A as a duplicate of question B because its answer is in question B's question, but not in one of its answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I wanted to ask a question about how to use an image which is in the asset catalog in the HTML of a `UIWebView`.

I first searched on Stack Overflow and found this:

[local html in UIWebView with images from Assets catalog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615004/local-html-in-uiwebview-with-images-from-assets-catalog)

From the question title, the question is asking for similar things. So I clicked on it and quickly scrolled the answers section. After reading the answer, I found it not very useful. Then I scrolled up to look at the question.

In the question, the OP says he knows how to use an image in the asset catalogs in HTML. And it is by using this code:

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<h1>My title</h1><img src='%@'/>", @"myImage1.png"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

What the OP didn't know how to do is how to use *resized* images from the asset catalog. But I don't need to know that.

Therefore, instead of one of the answers to the question that answers my question, the *question* actually answers my question.

Since I already found the answer, I did not post the question. But what if I posted the question? Will my question be closed as a duplicate of that question?

"Your question can be closed, but not because the other question answers your question. It is because your question and the other question are asking similar things," you might say.

Okay, let's say that the other question is not related to my question at all. In the question, the OP shows his code. In the code, there is a little part of it that answers my question.

Will my question be closed if the other question was like this?